# How to set the username and password as a hardcode in a WS-Security usernameToken police?

Tags: ws-security

How to set the username and password as a hardcode in a WS-Security usernameToken police?

```
....
<ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
    <ramp:user>admin</ramp:user>
    <ramp:password......> ???
</ramp:RampartConfig>   
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `<passwordCallbackClass>`

If you want to hardcode the password, define a class like this.

```
public class MyHardcodedPasswordHandler implements CallbackHandler {
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException,
            UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for (Callback callback : callbacks) {
            WSPasswordCallback pwcb = (WSPasswordCallback)callback;
            pwcb.setPassword("myPassword");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the rampart config

```
<passwordCallbackClass>something.something.MyHardcodedPasswordHandler</passwordCallbackClass>
```